# run Python (py file) in local machine via cloud server without python installed

Tags: python, cloud

Here is a problem. I write the python script on my local computer and generate the py file.
If I want to send it to others and they want to run py file without python installed.
Is it possible that they can run the py file via cloud server complier and pacakges installed in the cloud server and they doesn't need the install the python on their local machines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create executable using pyinstaller and you can send it to anyone without having python.

Install pyinstaller to your py

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Exe creation command

```
pyinstaller -onefile myscript.py
```